# SQLite where in

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have an app that allows filtering on some entities (places), and I have a local caching system that puts all the entities on a local database (using Room). When the user selects a different filtering a trigger a request from the remote api and I process the results to insert the ids on a different table.

So the information I present onscreen is always the entities (places) stored in the local database, filtered by a WHERE IN clause with those ids.

Now if the filter results in more than 1000 places, the SQL query fails, I guess this is a limitation of the Where IN clause, but how can I circunvent this?

This is the repository method:

```
 val placesResult = listResultDao.getListResults()
                .switchMap { listIds ->
                    placesDao.getPlaces(listIds)
                            .doOnNext {
                                Timber.v("PAGELIST - places list changed")
                            }
                }
```

DAO method:

```
   @Query("select * from Places where placeId in (:placesIds) order by distance, placeName ASC")
    fun getPlaces(placesIds: List<String>): Flowable<List<Place>>
```

ID list DAO method:

```
@Query("select id from list_results")
abstract fun getListResults(): Flowable<List<String>>
```

STacktrace:

```
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: too many SQL variables (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from Places where placeId in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) order by distance, placeName ASC
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1383)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:233)
       at io.soulpicks.android.model.db.PlacesDao_Impl$5.call(PlacesDao_Impl.java:489)
       at io.soulpicks.android.model.db.PlacesDao_Impl$5.call(PlacesDao_Impl.java:486)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RxRoom$4.apply(RxRoom.java:111)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RxRoom$4.apply(RxRoom.java:108)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.poll(FlowableMap.java:141)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.poll(FlowableFilter.java:91)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.poll(FlowableMap.java:80)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.poll(FlowableDoOnEach.java:156)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapSubscriber.drain(FlowableSwitchMap.java:268)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapInnerSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSwitchMap.java:392)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FlowableDoOnEach.java:81)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:57)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.tryOnNext(FlowableFilter.java:63)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFilter.java:52)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:100)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnConditionalSubscriber.runBackfused(FlowableObserveOn.java:680)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:172)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: but this would not circunvent the 1000 item limit would it?

Comment: It's not really a limit of `WHERE IN` but the number of variables that is limited by `SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER` to 999. https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html . You could try to work around it by passing in a raw comma-separated list but I believe Room makes it harder to insert raw SQL. Anyway, a long list like that comes with a code smell; I'd consider refactoring the database design here.

Comment: fair point, ill try the previous advice while i try to refactor... not sure how tho

Comment: yes it does seem to work